# Python turtle graphic window not showing up

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I was recently following a tutorial on turtle in python version 2.7.11. The problem is, the window for turtle graphic does not show up and in the python shell it reads the file path and then "Restart". I have also reinstalled python and I'm on mac OS X.10.11.4

thank you

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

brad = turtle.Turtle()
brad.shape("turtle")
brad.color("yellow")
brad.speed(2)

brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)

window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Comment: Did you indent correctly? `draw_square()` call should be outside of the function definition.

Comment: Indentation of the code in the question looks invalid. No indentation at all there.

Comment: ok how do i fix it

Comment: I posted an answer. Please compare the code in the answer with the code in the question (especially indentation)

Comment: ok thank you ill check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should indent correctly. Make sure the line which calls `draw_square()` should be outside of the function definition:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)

    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

---

[image: screenshot of the program running]